# Wine cannot execute a .exe file and gives error message "failed to set token information. Invalid function (1)"

Tags: usb, software-installation, wine, java

I have all wine 1.7 and 2.34 packages installed and I cannot run the poweragent.exe file after installation and configuration (windows 7, xp and global settings have been tried).
(The program is here: https://www.powertap.com/product/poweragent)
The message in the title appears followed by "cannot find java 1.7 or higher". Which is also installed.

I guess it's straight forward...Danger, amateur at sight! I have looked for answers but it's very confusing. :/

Thanks!

Comment: Please read and understand the answer below. Consider a native alternative: http://www.goldencheetah.org

Answer (score 1):

Even if you got the program to run somehow, programs running inside Wine cannot interface with USB devices.

You can either

- find a native Linux software for your power meter or
- run the program inside a Windows guest system inside a virtual machine on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David, I am looking at downloading gpart to 1.install windows on one side, and 2.install the ftdi drivers for the device (trying to figure out how) and run it with goldencheetah...Any suggestions or notes on these options? Thanks again! @celticwarrior